# Check sorted array for duplicates

Tags: java, android, arrays

I do have a sorted array that I want to check for duplicate entrys. Problem is I need to know where the duplicate was as its a multidiensional array and I need to remove the 2nd entry too. Also in the end I must have an array filled with values so just overwriting the duplicates with some dummy won't work. I have read about `Array.utils` doing the trick but I'D rather not import any other libaries and `Array.utils` isn't recognized so I would've to import that.

I also tried to write a little function myself

```
        Integer iIndex = 1;
   while (keepRunning2){
        if(phoneNameNumber[iIndex][0].equals(phoneNameNumber[iIndex-1][0])){
            keepRunning = true;
            tmp = new String[phoneNameNumber.length-1][2];
            int k = 0;
            int t=0;
            while(keepRunning){
                Log.wtf("running",String.valueOf(iIndex) + ":" + String.valueOf(k));
                tmp[t][0] = phoneNameNumber[k][0];
                tmp[t][1] = phoneNameNumber[k][1];
                if(k!=i-1){
                    k++;
                    t++;
                }else{
                    k=k+2;
                    t++;
                }
                if(t==tmp.length-1)
                    keepRunning=false;

            }
            phoneNameNumber = null;
            phoneNameNumber = new String[tmp.length][2];
            phoneNameNumber = tmp;
        }
        if(!(iIndex < phoneNameNumber.length-1)){
            keepRunning2 = false;
        }
        iIndex++;
    }
```

Buuuut... first it takes like 10 years to complete this and as this is for a UI of an app you can see that it should be alittle faster + for some reason after processing all of this it jumps back to while like keeppRunning2 'd never be set to false.

So does somebody know a solution?

and if sb wanna know where the data comes from: heres the activity

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

/**
 * Created by **** on 19.07.2016.
 */
public class newChatActivity extends Activity implements       View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Button bCreateChat;
Button bCancelChat;
EditText tchat_name;
//EditText tmembers;
CheckBox cBoxPrivateChat;
Spinner memberSpinner;
String members = "";
String lastContactName = "";
List<String> nameList,number;
String[][]phoneNameNumber,tmp;
String[] sortedNames;
Integer i = 0;
Integer memberCount = 0;
Boolean keepRunning = true;
Boolean keepRunning2 = true;

private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_chat);
    setTitle("Add New Chat");

    bCreateChat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateChat);
    bCancelChat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChatCance);
    tchat_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tchat_name);
    cBoxPrivateChat = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cBoxprivChat);
    memberSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.memberSpinner);


    bCreateChat.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCancelChat.setOnClickListener(this);

    loadAllContacts();
    sortedNames = new String[phoneNameNumber.length];
    Integer iIndex = 1;
   while (keepRunning2){
        if(phoneNameNumber[iIndex][0].equals(phoneNameNumber[iIndex-1][0])){
            keepRunning = true;
            tmp = new String[phoneNameNumber.length-1][2];
            int k = 0;
            int t=0;
            while(keepRunning){
                Log.wtf("running",String.valueOf(iIndex) + ":" + String.valueOf(k));
                tmp[t][0] = phoneNameNumber[k][0];
                tmp[t][1] = phoneNameNumber[k][1];
                if(k!=i-1){
                    k++;
                    t++;
                }else{
                    k=k+2;
                    t++;
                }
                if(t==tmp.length-1)
                    keepRunning=false;


            }
            phoneNameNumber = null;
            phoneNameNumber = new String[tmp.length][2];
            phoneNameNumber = tmp;
        }
        if(!(iIndex < phoneNameNumber.length-1)){
            keepRunning2 = false;
        }
        iIndex++;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<phoneNameNumber.length;i++){
        sortedNames[i] = phoneNameNumber[i][0];
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sortedNames);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    memberSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    memberSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bCreateChat:
                if (!tchat_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!members.isEmpty()) {
                    if(cBoxPrivateChat.isChecked()){
                        createChat("name=" + tchat_name.getText().toString() + "&members=" + members + ScrollingActivity.Identifier + "#");
                    }
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Keine Daten Eingegeben",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            break;
        case R.id.bChatCance:
            this.finish();
            break;
        default:
            if(v.getId() > 2000000 ){
                members = members.replace("#" + number.get(v.getId() - 2000000) + "#","");
                TextView delText = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
                delText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                memberCount = memberCount - 1;
                if(memberCount <= 1){
                    cBoxPrivateChat.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
    }
}

public void createChat(String Data){
    try {
        Boolean b = new createNewCHat().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,ScrollingActivity.ServerLocation + "/alterChat.php", Data).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScrollingActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position != 0 && !cBoxPrivateChat.isChecked()) {
        members = members + "#" + number.get(position) + "#";
        TextView MemberText = new TextView(this);
        MemberText.setId(2000000 + position);
        MemberText.setText(phoneNameNumber[position][0] + " " + phoneNameNumber[position][1]);
        LinearLayout memberLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.membersLayout);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        memberLayout.addView(MemberText, params);
        MemberText.setOnClickListener(this);
        memberCount++;
        if(memberCount > 1){
            cBoxPrivateChat.setEnabled(false);
            cBoxPrivateChat.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else if(position != 0 && cBoxPrivateChat.isChecked() && members.equals("")){
        members = members + "#" + number.get(position) + "#";
        TextView MemberText = new TextView(this);
        MemberText.setId(2000000 + position);
        MemberText.setText(phoneNameNumber[position][0] + " " + phoneNameNumber[position][1]);
        LinearLayout memberLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.membersLayout);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        memberLayout.addView(MemberText, params);
        MemberText.setOnClickListener(this);
        memberCount++;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


public void loadAllContacts(){
    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    number = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);


            nameList.add(0,"Select chat members");
            number.add(0,"");

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                if(!cursor.getString(nameIndex).equals(lastContactName)){
                    nameList.add(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
                    number.add(cursor.getString(numberIndex));
                    lastContactName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();

        }
        phoneNameNumber = new String[nameList.size()][2];

        for(int i = 0; i<nameList.size();i++){
            phoneNameNumber[i][0] = nameList.get(i);
            phoneNameNumber[i][1] = number.get(i);
        }

        Arrays.sort(phoneNameNumber, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
                final String time1 = entry1[0];
                final String time2 = entry2[0];
                return time1.compareTo(time2);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

oh and btw does somebody know why there are duplicates in the array? because if i simply use the list names on the spinner i dont have any duplicates

Comment: `while (keepRunning2){`: `keepRunning2` was not defined. (and I can imagine that one, but `phoneNameNumber` hasn't been defined too ... you could have provided fake one with some example values, you want to remove, and what you expect). BTW, if I would even try to answer this, I would need to know first, why do you use array, and not some List/Map/Set instead, where you can erase elements.

Comment: The most important thing to consider when programming is the structure of the data. Could you provide an example of how the data is structured?

Comment: well I do assign `phone name number` 3 times because i still dont fully understand how arrays work.. so the first one is to erase the old array ( cause I dont want some old data be still in there ) then I wnat to initialize the array and then i assign a value.

actually I am learning yes - for a week? no 
I neither use tutorials nor lectures whatsoever instead I had a little bit of knowledge and decided to build an app out of what i knew and now i try to expand the learned

also If u wanna see some really bad code - I included the full class above

Comment: it's sometimes worth to put few lines of context to question, like what is your level, etc, so people can adjust a bit the answer, either explaining more, or less. That code is ok for somebody just trying to learn to program (it has many bad-taste things, and several "bugs" which would crash it in some conditions, but it somewhat work), but it will take years to get to good level, especially if you don't put a bit of system into the learning. Trying to code things is good, but always allocate few hours to just read some theory and books. (avoid "in 21 days" or "professional" in title :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you probably wanted some function like this:

(but I didn't understand your "I need to know where duplicate was" ... why? And also your code doesn't use the other dimension in any way, only [0] is compared... so I mimick that in my code too, but maybe it is not what you wanted?)

```
import java.util.Arrays;  // Maybe all of your problem is that you had typo in import?
// This is language standard stuff, available everywhere IMHO

    /**
     * Removes duplicates and nulls from sorted array, first item (sortedArray[i][0]) is considered
     * for duplicates search, rest of values sortedArray[i][1..n] is not considered at all.
     * 
     * @param sortedArray
     *            sorted 2D String array, can have any 1 <= length in second dimension.
     * @return items with duplicate in [i][0] or null will be removed from result array.
     */
    public static String[][] removeDuplicateOrNullItems(final String[][] sortedArray) {
        // validate input
        if (null == sortedArray || sortedArray.length <= 1) {
            return sortedArray; // garbage in, garbage out
        }
        // search for first duplicate (if any)
        int i = 0;
        while (++i < sortedArray.length) {
            if (null == sortedArray[i][0] || sortedArray[i][0].equals(sortedArray[i - 1][0])) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == sortedArray.length) {
            return sortedArray; // no duplicate found, return input
        }
        // First duplicate is at index i, now compact the rest of array content (overwriting dupes)
        int newi = i; // will serve both as count of unique values, and compact-writing index
        while (++i < sortedArray.length) {
            if (null == sortedArray[i][0] || sortedArray[i][0].equals(sortedArray[i - 1][0])) {
                continue; // another duplicate, skip this one
            }
            sortedArray[newi++] = sortedArray[i]; // valid value, compact it
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(sortedArray, newi); // return the compacted result
    }

// demo how to call it:

        String[][] in = {{"A1", "A2"}, {"A1", "dupA"}, {null, null}, {"B1", "B2"}, {"B1", "dupB1"}, {"B1", "dupB2"}, {"C1", "C2"}};
//      String[][] in = {{"A1", "A2", "A3"}, {"B1", "B2", "B3"}};
//      String[][] in = null;

        String[][] out = removeDuplicateOrNullItems(in);
```

I tried to comment it a bit to give you idea what it is doing... although using debugger and stepping it line by line few times may help a lot more.

---

If you really want to avoid java.util.Arrays, then the last `return Arrays.copyOf...` should be replaced with this:

```
    final String[][] result = new String[newi][sortedArray[0].length];
    for (i = 0; i < newi; ++i) result[i] = sortedArray[i];
    return result;
```

---

added:
about those 3 assignments:

```
        phoneNameNumber = null;
        phoneNameNumber = new String[tmp.length][2];
        phoneNameNumber = tmp;
```

I don't know what you already know about programming, so this may be difficult.

`phoneNameNumber` is `String[][]` type, which is sort of address (pointer) to place in memory, where the array is stored (number of dimensions is not important ATM).

So you first set it to `null`, then to new allocated space, and finally to space where `tmp` is pointing already (sharing the same array with `tmp`). The second line with allocation of new memory is useless, it will be overwritten straight away by the third line, and the newly allocated memory will be made available for GC (Garbage Collector).

If you wanted to copy the values from `tmp` to the newly allocated area in memory (a real copy), you would have do a for loop, and assign `phoneNameNumber[i][j] = tmp[i][j];`. This would then share with `tmp` only the pointers to `String` itself, which is OK in Java, as `String` is immutable (can't change the value, so if you keep address of one string around, you can be sure it's content didn't change even when some other part of code is working with that pointer).

If you would do only `phoneNameNumber[i] = tmp[i];` to copy it, it would look at first sight the same (values in new `phoneNameNumber` would be same as in `tmp`. But there's difference, now the `phoneNameNumber` and `tmp` would share also the two String inner tiny arrays. So after such copy, if you would do `tmp[0][1] = null;`, the `phoneNameNumber[0][1]` would suddenly contain `null` too (because that area of memory storing those pointers to Strings is shared, so you are writing the null pointer there for both variables).

<s>Or to copy (true copy) array use `java.util.Arrays.copy***` methods.</s>

The first line of setting it to `null` is actually sometimes used in Java programs, to mark some memory for GC as "to be released", if you know you will not use it any more.

As you overwrite `phoneNameNumber` with another pointer right away, this is useless, the GC will collect the original memory also if you will just directly assign the `tmp` to it (losing the old value = ready for GC). Actually performance wise in such case the intermediate step nulling the old value hurts JVM+GC, as it has resolve two assignments instead of one, and the result will be same.

As you can see, I don't care about whether I copy or share parts of original array, using whichever is simpler. So that method is written in a way that it will modify the original input. If you would want to keep it intact (and receive the result in different array), you would have to call it with copy of input array, let it mess up with the copy:
`String[][] out = removeDuplicateOrNullItems(Arrays.copyOf(in, in.length));`
EDIT: **BUG** ^^ this copyOf, or in.clone() is not deep copy, creating copies
on all levels of dimension, but only creating copy of the upper array, sharing everything below between.

Example in code:

```
// INIT

String[][] in = {{"A1", "A2"}, {"B1", "B2"}};
// in is array of 2 references (pointers) at String[] value.
// Let's say in@adr1 = [@r1, @r2] (at address @adr1 in memory)
// @r1 = array of two references to Strings [@"A1", @"A2"], @r2 = [@"B1", @"B2"]
String[][] inCopy = in.clone();
// inCopy has copy of top level array (content of in@adr1) at address @adr2
// inCopy@adr2 = [@r1, @r2];  so this is in new memory,
// but the values are old @r1 and @r2, sharing the second level arrays with "in"

// modification CASE 1

String[] x = {"X1", "X2"};  // x@adr3 = [@"X1", @"X2"]
in[0] = x;
// in@adr1 = [x@adr3, @r2], so in = [[X1, X2], [B1, B2]]
// inCopy@adr2 = [@r1, @r2], so inCopy = [[A1, A2], [B1, B2]]

// modification CASE 2 (on deeper level, where clone/copyOf didn't create copy)

in[1][0] = "X";  // @r2[0] modified to contain @"X";
// in@adr1 = [x@adr3, @r2], @r2 = [@"X", @"B2"],  in = [[X1, X2], [X, B2]]
// inCopy@adr2 = [@r1, @r2] (same @r2!), so inCopy = [[A1, A2], [X, B2]]
```

As you can see, in second case the inCopy is modified by the modification of in[1][0]. To prevent this, you have to copy multidimensional arrays per depth:

```
String[][] in = {{"A1", "A2"}, {"B1", "B2"}};
String[][] inCopy = new String[in.length][in[0].length];
// inner arrays of inCopy are cloned to new memory, not shared with "in"
for (int i = 0; i < in.length; ++i) {
    inCopy[i] = in[i].clone();
}
```

But you may take this as a warning, that it's not that difficult to create a major mistake in your assumptions. :/ Always test your code... :D (automated testing with Unit Tests is perfect for such cases). Also after writing first good version, it never hurts to step it over in debugger step by step, just to verify it works as you intended (plus it helps to learn a lot).

---

Usually, when you are creating your own methods, it's a bit better to act on inputs as immutable values, and to not modify them (in ideal world my method would create that copy of array at the very beginning of it). That leads to fewer surprise bugs later, when you call your API thinking it will return just the modified array as new copy, but not modify the input one. (Java's class `Date` is notoriously catching me unprepared, when I ask for some value stored for UI, and do some calculations with it to see if for example the date will expire in 14 days, and then I wonder why the value in UI did change (as I did the calculation over the original memory, not copying it). `String` is immutable, so whenever you change a string to some new value, you can bet you did receive new pointer, and if other code is holding the old one directly, it does still see the old String. = less surprising for programmers constantly in hurry.

Hmmm... this is getting too long. If you didn't figure out what I'm talking about, try to search for how computer memory works, what is memory allocation and then in Java, how variables are stored [found something here, looks like free lecture notes from uni course](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dewan/comp401/s09/Class%20Notes/8_Pointers_Notes.pdf). If you are new to programming, it may be quite confusing at first, but then search for some kids books describing how computer works, or some early books on programming (1970-1990 era), that should give you good base to understand what is happening inside, when you will read more about JVM.

Comment: Hmm thanks alot thats extremly helpfull and I honestly learned alot from that ( altough my brain does hurt from all that variable to memory and copy or deepcoopy stuuf xD) just what do u mean with immutable values?

Comment: In short: Immutable class -> you instantiate it with value, like `String s = "hello";` and that's it, that particular instance of Java String will not change ever. If you change some char in that string, internally it will be copied to new memory, modified, and new instance of String will be created with it (frozen too). So if you do lot of modifications with String, you are actually copying around quite some memory, that's why `StringBuilder` exists in Java. (and why you never should benchmark C++ `std::string` against Java `String`, because that's like comparing airplane vs car).

Comment: @BAAAZINGA: using immutables (String/BigDecimal/...) is less prone to programmer's errors (to use by accident already modified value, expecting the old one, or other way), and often leads to simpler/easier to read source. And easier to create multithread version. Extra cost is performance of all those copy-on-write operations (if not avoided). That's usually little cost, compared to the cost of hunting some weird bug. Anyway, use Internet. (I was learning to code w/o computer (paper+pen and 4h of HW time weekly) and w/o Internet (books only)). Maybe was better, less distractions. :D

Answer (score 0):

Java is a powerful language because it has useful libraries. I recommend you use ArrayList as it will improve your efficiency, performance, and complexity.

This is the really best I can think of if you want to solve this kind of problem without using those libraries.

```
// I don't know what's your phoneNameNumber, but I assume it is 2D string array:
String[][] phoneNameNumber = new String[][];
String duplicatedIndicesString = "";

// Loop through phoneNameNumber
for (int i=0; i<phoneNameNumber.length; i++) {
    // Find duplicates
    for (int i2=0; i<phoneNameNumber.length; i2++) {
        boolean duplicated = true;

        for (int j=0; j<phoneNameNumber[i2].length; j++) {
            if (phoneNameNumber[i][j].equals(phoneNameNumber[i2].j) == false) {
                // Not duplicate for this i2
                duplicated = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(duplicated == true) {
            duplicatedIndicesString += i2;
            if (i2!=phoneNameNumber.length-1) {
                // Store duplicated index for later dynamic allocation..
                duplicatedIndicesString += ",";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Now let's copy results to a new array.
String[] duplicatedIndicesStringArray = duplicatedIndicesString.split(",");
String[][] resultPhoneNameNumber = new String[phoneNameNumber.length - dupicatedIndices.length][2];
int resultIndex = 0;

for (int i=0; i<phoneNameNumber.length; i++) {
    boolean duplicated = false;

    for (j=0; j<duplicatedIndicesStringArray.length; j++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(duplicatedIndicesStringArray[j]) == i) {
            duplicated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (duplicated == false) {
        resultPhoneNameNumber[resultIndex] = phoneNameNumber[i];
        resultIndex++;
    }
}
```

This is probably the ugliest code I've wrote for a while. I did it because I took too much morning coffee. Think before you code.